# how do I know which function need to be followed by a close resource operation

Tags: python

I am new to Python and feel confused about when I should call close.

For instance, consider this [example from the csv documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-examples).

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

There is no reader.close() in the end of this task.

Q> How do I find out whether or not a function call need to be followed by a close call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions that return resources that need to be cleaned up will have documentation that explains that.  `csv.reader` doesn't open a file, or otherwise create a closable resource.  The `open` call does, but the `with` statement takes care of closing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you need to call close is when you must release system resources.  By-in-large this is only true for file handles.  General objects, such as the csv reader, do not have to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave doesn't need a close, because the file that was opened was handled by the `with` (similar to the `using` of C#).

Now, if your example had been this, there would be a `close()`:

```
import csv
f = open('some.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print row
f.close()
```

The two are effectively the same thing, but the `with` takes care of failures during run to make sure the file handle (`f`) is closed. If there was a problem between the `open` and `close` here, you'd still have an open file resource.

EDIT:
The `with` is the same as this:

```
import csv
f = open('some.csv', 'rb')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
finally:
    f.close()
```